# Discord.js Source server query

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord.js bot that will get data from the CS:GO server and shows it in embed that will be edited and updated (for example every 2 minutes). I still have some problems with the code, currently I stuck with the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined"

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");
var SourceQuery = require('sourcequery');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");


client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`bot is ready`);
});

client.on("ready", (message, embed) => {
     function queryserver(ip, port, sendChannel) {
      let sq = new SourceQuery(1000);
      console.log(ip + "  " + port);
      sq.open(ip, port);
      sq.getInfo(function (err, info) {
        
        if (!err) {
          sq.getPlayers(function (err, players) {
            if (!err) {
              console.log(sq.address);
              var counter = 0;
              playersname = "";
              for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                playersname = playersname + players[i].name + "\n";
                if (counter == players.length - 1) {
                  client.channels.cache.get(sendChannel).send({
                    embed: {
                      color: 3066993,
                      fields: [{
                        name: "Server name",
                        value: "**" + info.name + "**"
                      },
                      {
                        name: "IP",
                        value: ip + ":" + port,
                        "inline": true
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Mapa",
                        value: info.map,
                        "inline": true
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Max slots",
                        value: info.maxplayers,
                        "inline": true
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Online",
                        value: info.players,
                        "inline": true
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Player list",
                        value: "```" + playersname + "```"
                      }
                      ],
                      timestamp: new Date(),
                      footer: {
                        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                        text: "Last update:"
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
                counter++;
              }
            }
            else {
              console.log("Error...");
              message.channel.send("Error...");
            }
          });
        }
        else {
          console.log("Error...");
          message.channel.send("Error...");
        }
      });
    };


   setInterval(function() {
    queryserver(`216.52.148.47`, `27015`, `834355545879347233`);
      message.edit(embed)
  }, 2000);
});


client.login(config.token);
````

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The `ready` event for `Client` does not have any parameters, so both `message` and `embed` are undefined. Source: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready

Comment: Also there is no need to use 2 `ready` events.

Comment: The second event listener should be listening for `message`, not `ready`.